# How to get remote machine OS version in .Net, without WMI?

Tags: c#, .net

Is there any way to get OS version of remote machine in .Net(C#)? 
Using of WMI is not acceptable for me.

I have IP address of remote machine :) and administrator credentials

Comment: My users should have possibility do not use WMI (it is requirement and I can't change this)

Comment: So, how did you get the IP? How are they connecting to you?

Comment: WMI is the correct way to do this

Comment: I have the list of IP's (it is user's input)

Comment: @Quandary He has the admin account details for the remote machines, so hardly 'hacking'...

Comment: That could be a lie! Besides, he may have a only a shell running as admin.

Comment: @Quandary I'm not hacker, you may believe me or not it is your own business. I thought this resource is used for resolving not standard problems, if I can use the standard approach I'm not asking the questions
Thanks everybody for help!

Comment: @Quandary If you want people to read your comment responses, please include their @username in your response. That way they will get notified.

Answer (score 10):

based on sgmoore answer with some usings

```
    public string GetOsVersion(string ipAddress)
    {
        using (var reg = RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, ipAddress))
        using (var key = reg.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\"))
        {
            return string.Format("Name:{0}, Version:{1}", key.GetValue("ProductName"), key.GetValue("CurrentVersion"));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have administrator credentials for the remote machine you could use [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553) to run a command remotely to get the OS version e.g.

> CMD /c ver

You can write a wrapper to run PsExec in C# by using the [Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) class.

Comment: This makes sense, I need to clarify this approach with my lead, but it is good suggestion. Thanks

Comment: I can't imagine threading that many commands externally, I wonder what the overhead would be on that? I have a few hundred computers on my network that I would have to do this too.

Answer (score 1):

Providing you have remote registry access,

```
 var reg = Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive.LocalMachine, ipaddress); 
 var key = reg.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\");
 string version = (string) key.GetValue("CurrentVersion");
 reg.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

One can use pinvoke

`[DllImport("Netapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern int NetServerGetInfo(string serverName, int level, out IntPtr serverInfo);`

See http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/netapi32/netservergetinfo.html for marshalling types and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370624(v=vs.85).aspx for usage

Answer (score 1):

Reading registry values is the best solution, but sometimes, when you don't have WMI and RemoteRegedit service is not working, you can use another option -> SystemInfo.exe

So you need..

**Powershell reference:**

```
using System.Management.Automation; //Get via NuGet "Microsoft.Powershell.X.ReferenceAssemblies"
                                   //where X = your ps preferred version 
                                  //-> in this example I'm using version 5
```

**Some method for powershell invoke:**

```
    private static List<PSObject> InvokePowershell(string command, string remoteMachine = null)
    {
        //In powershell 5 version, we don't have to use Runspace... PoweShell class is enough
        List<PSObject> result = new List<PSObject>();

        using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
        {
            //If remoteMachine is set, we have to change our ps command for remote invoke
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(remoteMachine))
            {
                command = string.Format("Invoke-Command -ComputerName {0} -ScriptBlock{{{1}}}", remoteMachine, command);
            }

            ps.AddScript(command);

            return ps.Invoke().Cast<PSObject>().ToList();
        }

    }
```

**And simply using example:**

```
string command = "systeminfo /fo LIST | Select-String \"System Type\", \"OS Name\", \"OS Version\"";
List<PSObject> resultOS = InvokePowershell(command, remoteMachineName);

string nameOS = resultOS.Find(obj => obj.ToString().Contains("OS Name")).ToString().Split(':').Last().Trim();
string versionOS = resultOS.Find(obj => obj.ToString().ContainsString("OS Version")).ToString().Split(null).Last().Trim();
string architectureOS = resultOS.Find(obj => obj.ToString().ContainsString("System Type")).ToString().Split(':').Last().Trim();
```

SystemInfo.exe has a lot more data, just type systeminfo in PS and you can choose what you want.
Also.. in PS 5 there is modernization for SystemInfo via Get-ComputerInfo, but for this purpose is SystemInfo better, because has better compatibility (even PS version 2) and is faster